# Api Apps Vs Api Management

Tags: azure

I am looking for scalable hosting for an API but I am getting a little confused with Azure.  Ideally I want something that means I don't have to manage OS updates and security, just deploy my API code.

Is this possible with Azure?  What do I need to sign up for?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are looking for the **Platform as a service** offer. Check [What is PaaS?](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-paas/). For the API deployment you should check the [Azure App Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/). Azure API Management is for advanced API management or when you want to expose multiple APIs using a single gateway.